# How can I split a Bytes32 source into two halfs and store them in Bytes16?

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32

I want to split a 32 Byte source: first half in Bytes16 half1; second half in Bytes16 half2. My code works, however only for dynamic array, not with fixed size 16.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract cut {

    function cutSha(bytes32 source) constant returns (bytes, bytes) {
        bytes memory half1 = new bytes(16);
        bytes memory half2 = new bytes(16);
        for (uint j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                half1[j] = source[j];
                half2[j] = source[j+16];
        }
        return (half1, half2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the halfs are just the first / last 16 bytes there should be an efficient way, like using inline assembly and mload?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This code is no longer correct on modern versions of Solidity. Please see Sergey Kaunov's [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/134662/100).**

---

It is possible to do this with assembly:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract c {
    event trace(bytes32 x, bytes16 a, bytes16 b);

    function foo(bytes32 source) {
        bytes16[2] memory y = [bytes16(0), 0];
        assembly {
            mstore(y, source)
            mstore(add(y, 16), source)
        }
        trace(source, y[0], y[1]);
    }
}
```

For example, converting bytes from the string "what a wonderful world!", produces this after using 2245 gas:

```
trace[
  "0x77686174206120776f6e64657266756c20776f726c6421000000000000000000",
  "0x77686174206120776f6e64657266756c",
  "0x20776f726c6421000000000000000000"
]
```

**NB**: the code relies on the internal data representation that may be subject to change in later versions of Solidity or interfere with Solidity optimizer in an unpredictable ways.

Comment: Just saw this now. Thank you very much, will compare now to my own solution posted below.

Comment: How do we change your code so that I can take input of 56 characters and split them into two bytes32?

Comment: I don't understand why the second mstore doesn't need to also increment the source address.

Comment: @jdbertron, this code worked on ancient version of Solidity. See another answer (with type conversions) for modern solution.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution using inline assembly:

```
contract cutByte32 {

  //"0xa9c40ddcb43ebbc83add97b8f9f361f12b19bceff2f76b68f66b5bb1812365a9"
  //use this as remix command

  function cut(bytes32 sha) constant returns (bytes16 half1, bytes16 half2) {
    assembly {
      let freemem_pointer := mload(0x40)
      mstore(add(freemem_pointer,0x00), sha)
      half1 := mload(add(freemem_pointer,0x00))
      half2 := mload(add(freemem_pointer,0x10))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, that is nice. but can you explain a bit what `mload(0x40)` means?

Comment: Thank you, at the address 0x40 (solidity definition) the pointer (/address) for the next free slot on the memory is stored. Loading it first into the freemem_pointer variable makes sure I don't overwrite anything in memory. However I assume there are even better solutions. If I would new at what address the parameter value "bytes32 sha" is stored I don't need to store it again and can directly start to read it out 16byte wise.

Comment: How do we change your code so that I can take input of 56 characters and split them into two bytes32?

Answer (score 2):

It's [now possible to use type conversions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/types.html#explicit-conversions) to do it in a couple of lines.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract cut {

    function cutSha(bytes32 source) 
        public 
        returns (bytes16 half1, bytes16 half2) 
    {
        half1 = bytes16(source);
        half2 = bytes16(uint128(uint256(source)));
        
    }
}
```

PS Sorry if this code will need any linting -- can't test it right now, this is just illustration for the idea; so any corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with uints

```
   function bytesChunck(bytes32 source, uint start, uint numBytes) constant returns(uint _result){
                uint counter = 0;
                uint result;

                for(uint i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
                    result += uint8(source[start + i]);
                }
                return result;
        }
```

but [Reading bytes from bytes32 returns zero value (except first one)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/reading-bytes-from-bytes32-returns-zero-value-except-first-one)