# Splitting bytes9 into 3 parts

Tags: solidity, contract-development

From the example [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13143/how-can-i-split-a-bytes32-source-into-two-halfs-and-store-them-in-bytes16), I could split bytes32 to bytes16. But I am unable to use a similar approach to split bytes9 into three parts. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

```
//working
    function split2(bytes32 source) constant returns (bytes16, bytes16){
        bytes16[2] memory y = [bytes16(0), 0];
        assembly {
            mstore(y, source)
            mstore(add(y, 16), source)
        }
        return (y[0], y[1]);
    }

//not working
    function split3(bytes9 source) constant returns (bytes3, bytes3, bytes3){
        bytes3[3] memory y = [bytes3(0), 0, 0];
        assembly {
            mstore(y, source)
            mstore(add(y, 3), source)
            mstore(add(y, 6), source)
        }
        return (y[0], y[1], y[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
function split3(bytes9 source) public pure returns(bytes3, bytes3, bytes3) {
    bytes3[3] memory x = [bytes3(0), 0, 0];

    assembly {
        mstore(x, source)
        mstore(add(x, 29), source)
        mstore(add(x, 58), source)
    }
    return (x[0], x[1], x[2]);
}
```

The problem is that your address offsets are going the wrong way.

This is what you are aiming for in the `x` array (one column per byte):

```
0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
<--- x[0] ---------------------><--- x[1] ---------------------><--- x[2] --------------------->
SSSSSSSSS                    SSSSSSSSS                    SSSSSSSSS
111                             222                             333
```

Each element of `x` is actually a 32-byte word, despite appearances. `SSSSSSSSS` is your bytes9 `source`. `111` is your first bytes3 returned, `222` is your second bytes3 returned, and `333` is your third.  Solidity takes care of masking off the redundant extra bytes that are set outside the `bytes3` quantities.

(This technique is a bit of a nasty hack, IMHO, and confusing to boot.)

Comment: Great answer. It took me a while to understand the offsets, though the diagram does help. For others struggling like I did: the start of the first `bytes3` in the array is at `x+0`. The second is at `x+32`, and the third is at `x+64`. In the source, the offset of the first three bytes is `0`, the second three bytes is `3`, and the third three bytes is `6`. So to copy everything to the right place, we take `x` and add the offset of the `bytes3` we care about and then _subtract_ the offset of the bytes we care about in the source. The offsets are then `x+0-0`, `x+32-3`, and `x+64-6`.

Comment: Thank you @benjaminion and smarx. Both answers helped me understand.

benjaminion, you mentioned, this to be a bad hack. What would be the right way? I just discovered passing strings as function argument is a bad idea becasue of gas issues, so I am replacing string with bytesn. Do you suggest, I just stick to bytes32?

Comment: At the moment there is no really efficient work around for all cases. At some point the EVM will have a [SHR](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-145.md) instruction added, so it will be really cheap to do, say, `x = (source >> 24) & 0xffffff` to extract bytes 3-5 (you can do this today, but the cost may be high if the compiler decides to do `>>` with an `EXP` opcode, which it sometimes does. For certain cases, something like `x = (source / 0x1000000)&0xffffff` could be efficient.